# Resolve implicit parameter from super type

Tags: scala, typeclass, superclass, implicit, type-members

Is it possible to resolve an implicit parameter for a type B if an implicit is defined for its super type A?

Here is an example :

I have an Enumerable typeclass :

```
trait Enumerable[A] {

  def name(a: A): String

  def list: List[A] 

  //... other methods
}

object Enumeration {
  def name[A, T >: A](a: A)(implicit ev: Enumerable[T]) = ev.name(a)

  def list[T](implicit ev: Enumerable[T]) = ev.list

  // ...
}
```

Then I define an instance of enumerable :

```
sealed trait Season

case object Winter extends Season
case object Spring extends Season
case object Summer extends Season
case object Fall extends Season

implicit val seasonEnumerable = new Enumerable[Season] {
  override def list: List[Season] = List(Winter, Spring, Summer, Fall)
}

// working : 
Enumeration.name(Winter: Season) shouldBe "winter"

// faling : 
Enumeration.name(Winter) shouldBe "winter"
```

Enumeration.name(Winter) is failing if I don't tell scalac that Winter is a Season. I've specified that the implicit parameter in the 'name' method signature is a supertype of A, but it's not sufficient...

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eduardo's answer explains why the version with `[A, T >: A]` doesn't work. But there is a simpler solution to the problem than he gives: instead of introducing `T` infer as a type parameter, introduce it by an existential type:

```
def name[A](a: A)(implicit ev: Enumerable[T >: A] forSome { type T }) = ev.name(a)
```

Or, using a shorthand,

```
def name[A](a: A)(implicit ev: Enumerable[_ >: A]) = ev.name(a)
```

Then the compiler only has to decide what `T` is when looking for `ev`.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks :) 
Could you explain the difference between  
def name[A](a: A)(implicit ev: Enumerable[_ >: A]) = ev.name(a)  
and    def name[A, T >: A](a: A)(implicit ev: Enumerable[T]) = ev.name(a) ?

Comment: I've expanded the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common inconvenience whenever you need type-dependent types to be inferred. Your method

```
def name[A, T >: A](a: A)(implicit ev: Enumerable[T])
```

when called on `Winter`, first `A` will be inferred to `Winter.type` and then `T` to be `A`, as it conforms to that bound and there are no more constraints on it at that point. Then of course the compiler won't find an instance of `Enumerable[Winter.type]`.

There's an easy solution with type members though:

```
trait AnyEnumerable {

  type E

  def name[A <: E](a: A): String
  def list: List[E]
}

object Enumeration {

  def name[A](a: A)(implicit ev: AnyEnumerable { type E >: A }) = ev.name(a)
  def list[T](implicit ev: AnyEnumerable { type E = T }) = ev.list
  // ...
}

// an implicit for `Season`
implicit val seasonEnumerable: AnyEnumerable { type E = Season } = 
  new AnyEnumerable {

    type E = Season

    def name[A <: Season](a: A): String = a.toString
    def list: List[Season] = List(Winter, Spring, Summer, Fall)
  }

// compiles!
val zzz = Enumeration.name(Winter)
```